# Why string literals are comparable with pointers?

Tags: c, string-literals

If we say:

```
 char *p="name";
```

then how can we do

```
if(p=="name"){
 printf("able"};//this if condition is true but why?
```

as "name" here is a string literal and `p` is a pointer which holds the base address of the string then why the above statement works fine?

Comment: It is a compiler optimization.  One that you cannot rely on.

Comment: Extremely similar question to the one @YuHao points out. Same course material?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It is unspecified behavior whether identical string literals can be considered the same and thus have the same address. So this is not portable behavior. From the draft C99 standard section `6.4.5` *String literals*:

> It is unspecified whether these arrays are distinct provided their elements have the
>   appropriate values. [...]

If you want to compare two string you should use [strcmp](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strcmp).

Answer (score 2):

The C Standard allows the comparison to be true, but it is also allowed to be false (the behavior is *unspecified*). It depends on the compiler performing common string merging (for which gcc has an option to turn it on or off).

From the gcc 4.8.1 manual:

> `-fmerge-constants`
>      Attempt to merge identical constants (string constants and floating-point constants)
>      across compilation units.
>
> This option is the default for optimized compilation if the assembler and linker support it.
>   Use `-fno-merge-constants` to inhibit this behavior.
>      Enabled at levels -O, -O2, -O3, -Os.
>
> `-fmerge-all-constants`
>      Attempt to merge identical constants and identical variables.

So what you observe is a compiler performing string merging for the two `"name"` literals.

Answer (score 1):

String literals are nothing memory references hence when you do `char *p="name";` this, it means nothing but:

```
     |n |a |m | e
    /
   p
```

`p` points to first character of the string literal. So doing this:

`p=="name"` evaluates to  `someAddress==someAddress`. However this behavior is unspecified.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, let's disect what this does.

p is a pointer to `name\0`. So, here you are comparing `p` (a pointer) to `"name"` (also a pointer). Well, the only way this will every be true is if somewhere you have `p="name"` and even then, `"name"` is not guaranteed to point to the same place everywhere.

I believe what you are actually looking for is either `strcmp` to compare the entire string or your wanting to do `if (*p == 'n')` to compare the first character of the `p` string to the `n` character

You want to use `strcmp() == 0` to compare strings instead of a simple `==`, which will just compare if the pointers are the same.

The expression `strcmp( p, "name") == 0` will check if the contents of the two strings are the same.